# Linked document with PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

I would like use Linked document with query method on PouchDB for join two types of my documents.

My code is working, but is not dynamic :

```
const join = (doc) => {
  if (doc.mediasId === '3') {
    return emit(doc);
  }
}

Canvas.query(join, {include_docs: true}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.setState({
    canvas: data.rows
  });
});
```

I would like replace '3' (in the test) by dynamic number. If i add number parameter on my join function, i have an error about this ...

Anyone have idea for use dynamic 'id' on linked document PouchDB ?

Thank you !

Comment: What error do you get? We can't very well help you solve an error you won't disclose.

Answer (score 0):

As you are building an index to be searched, a dynamic key would not work - otherwise the system would have to build an index for every possible value.

To build the index, you emit a key and a value. The key is the first parameter of "emit" and the value is the second parameter (which contains the information you want).

The index is sorted by the key. I am not sure what the key is in your case - but it would be the thing you are trying to find - eg. "person_name" or "car_colour". To make use of the CouchDb "linked document" feature you have to emit an "_id" in the value and use the "include_docs" option. The value of the "_id" (the "link") exists as a value in the first document. That allows you to search by the key from the first document and access the values of the linked second document.

There is a better description than this in the PouchDb [documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) on "query" and example like this...

To build the index:

```
function my_index(doc) {
  // join artist data to albums
  if (doc.type === 'album') {
    emit(doc.name, {_id : doc.artistId, albumYear : doc.year});
  }
}
```

and then query the index, getting the linked document back:

```
db.query(my_index, {key: "Dark Side Of The Moon", include_docs : true}).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The "my_index" function should be kept in a design document in the database for efficiency, but it is best to read the documentation for that. Hope this helps.